# What does "highlight products" mean?

Tags: meaning, questions

*"I thought I would show you guys some of the highlight products for 2017 that I fell in love with, and I think you should know about. "*

Please I'd like to ask about what exactly does the "*highlight products*" in this sentence mean. Does it refer to the products which are important or really helpful? Like the things/products that I must have in my daily life?

I'd be appreciating if somebody can answer my question. Thanks!!!

Comment: Highlight product means the product that became the highlight of that year, it can the the most beautiful one that is shelfed in front of the store, or the most prominent one, usually placed on the heading of a website with the biggest picture, written in big words, etc. (in essence, something that provokes or catches your attention in a single glance usually is a good nomination to become the highlight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [highlight, verb, to emphasize or make prominent.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/highlight?s=t)

> "I thought I would show you guys some of the highlight products for
>   2017 that I fell in love with, and I think you should know about. "

This would imply that they are feature products that the writer would like to bring attention too.  It is not clear if this is because they are best selling, most advertised of subjectively liked.  Highlight is often used for emphasis.

That being said the sentence doesn't read very well to me because 2017 is in the past and "highlight" is effectively to shine a light on in the present, I would perhaps phrase it as

- some of the products that I would like to highlight
- the highlights of 2017
- the product highlights of 2017
- the highlighted products of 2017
- the prominent (or best selling) products of 2017